# WCF Service Bus Service failing to start with configuration error "collection already contains an item of the same type"

Tags: wcf, wcf-configuration, azureservicebus

I am exposing my windows service via Service Bus, follwoing is my configuration file.
I am getting strange error (all of sudden it start coming, though no change in code/config. It was working fine before.

One23InsightService failed to start. Exception Message:-The value could not be added to the collection, as the collection already contains an item of the same type: 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.TransportClientEndpointBehavior'. This collection only supports one instance of each type.
Parameter name: item
I have two endpoints with different interfaces, but same behavior configuration.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="One234C.Service.WCFNetTCPContract.InsightSrcDataService">
        <endpoint 
          name="SrcWeb"
          address="sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/09C3FA14-D449-4EA0-A829-3B7BD06598C2" 
                  binding="netTcpRelayBinding" 
                  contract="One234C.Service.Interface.IOne23SrcService" 
                  bindingConfiguration="Hybrid" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="sbTokenProvider" />

        <endpoint 
          name="AdminServiceEndpoint"
          address="sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/09C3FA14-D449-4EA0-A829-3B7BD06598C2" 
                  binding="netTcpRelayBinding" 
                  contract="One234C.Service.AdminInterface.IOne23AdminService" 
                  bindingConfiguration="Hybrid" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="sbTokenProvider" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpRelayBinding>
        <binding name="Hybrid" connectionMode="Hybrid" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpRelayBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" httpsGetEnabled="False" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="sbTokenProvider">
          <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
            <tokenProvider>
              <sharedSecret issuerName="owner" issuerSecret="asdfadfdfasdfasdfasdfsadfsadfsadfsdaf=" />
            </tokenProvider>
          </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
      <!-- In this extension section we are introducing all known service bus extensions. User can remove the ones they don't need. -->
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="connectionStatusBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.ConnectionStatusElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="transportClientEndpointBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TransportClientEndpointBehaviorElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="serviceRegistrySettings" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.ServiceRegistrySettingsElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="netMessagingTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingTransportExtensionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="tcpRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TcpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="httpRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.HttpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="httpsRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.HttpsRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="onewayRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.RelayedOnewayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>
      <bindingExtensions>
        <add name="basicHttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.BasicHttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="webHttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.WebHttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="ws2007HttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.WS2007HttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="netTcpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetTcpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="netOnewayRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetOnewayRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="netEventRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetEventRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="netMessagingBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </bindingExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Well did you try creating a new behavior and assigning it to one or other endpoint?

Comment: @hugh yes I tried that too. it didn't fix my problem. I created installer of that, could it be related to registry corruption?

Comment: Does it work with just a single endpoint in the config?

Comment: @hugh yes with one endpoint it worked. but I need two endpoint, is there any other way to configure it please.

Comment: @hugh I got the fix, I gave same address to both the endpoint, it must be different someway, I corrected and it is working now. Thanks hugh.

Comment: Please add this as athe answer so it helps others with the same problem. Or if you want I can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the fix, I gave same address to both the endpoint, it must be different someway, I corrected and it is working now.